# How many number of android devices can gradle android plugin support?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, broken-pipe

I have added 5 devices to my jenkins slave and am getting a `broken pipe error` for gradle install task.

> `com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Broken pipe`

I set the `ANDROID_SERIAL` var to direct the gradle to a particular device for gradle install. However, my adb lists all devices, and I am able to install the apk from adb. If I unplug one of the devices the gradle install works fine.

Do we have limitations on how many devices gradle can support?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the limitations, but ANDROID_SERIAL is now supported in the Android Gradle plugin from 0.14.0 (2014/10/31) and after.